# When should an array name be treated as a pointer and when does it just represent the array itself?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I just made a test program after reading the book and the result turned out confusing:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        char text[] = "hello!";

        printf("sizeof(text):%d  sizeof(text+2):%d  sizeof(text[0]):%d \n",(int)sizeof(text), sizeof(text+2), sizeof(text[0]));
        printf("text:%p sizeof(text):%d      &text:%p sizeof(&text):%d \n",text, sizeof(text), &text, sizeof(&text));
        printf("text+1:%p  &text+1:%p  \n", text+1, &text+1);

        return 0;
    }
```

The result：

```
sizeof(text):7  sizeof(text+2):4  sizeof(text[0]):1 
text:0xbfc8769d sizeof(text):7      &text:0xbfc8769d sizeof(&text):4 
text+1:0xbfc8769e  &text+1:0xbfc876a4
```

What makes me feel confused are:

1. why the value of 'sizeof(text)' is 7 whereas 'sizeof(text+2)' is 4
2. what's the difference between 'text' and '&text'?

Comment: The array-to-pointer decay happens "when it's necessary". For example, it's necessary in `text + 2`, since the `+` expression wouldn't otherwise make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
text+2
```

is a pointer to the 3rd element in the array, so sizeof results in the size of the pointer

text is the array while &text is a pointer to the array
text[1] is the second element in the array, but (&text)[1] points to the first element after the array (in that case equal to &text[7])

Answer (score 1):

Important: arrays are not pointer

they degrade to pointer if using them in contexts that expect a pointer.

- `sizeof(text)` gets the array at a whole so it outputs 7;
- `sizeof(text+2)` pointer arithmetic let the array degrade to a pointer
- `sizeof(text[0])`size of an element of course
- `sizeof(&text)` size of the pointer to the array. obviously a pointer too

using the address operates on an array explicitly retrieves a pointer to an array of that specific type (in your case `char[7]`. that pointer has the same address but a different type than a to-pointer-degraded array.

so the difference between `text+1` and `&text+1` should also be obvious. the first one increments the char pointer by one element --> points one element behind the first one. the second points to the second 7-element-char-array behind the first one.